# Can't going to next page in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

### carrier/components/index.vue

```
<d-button  @click.native = "addCarrier();"><i class="icon icon-sm"></i><span>New</span></i></d-button>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { ROAST_CONFIG } from '../../../../config/config.js';

import CarrierAdd from  './Add.vue';

var baseUrl = ROAST_CONFIG.API_URL;
export default {
    components: {
        'carrier-add':CarrierAdd,
    },
    data () {
        return {
            form: {
                showTop: false,
                componentLoading:true,
            },
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            this.componentLoading = false;    
        },500);
    },
    methods: {
        addCarrier() {

            alert(this.$parent.currentComponent);
            this.$parent.currentComponent = "carrier-add";
            this.$router.push({name:"CarriersNew"});
        }
    }
}
```

### carrier/components/Add.vue

```
<template>
   <h1>Carrier Add</h1>
</template>
```

### route.js

import Carriers from 'page/admin/carriers/index.vue';

```
 { path: '/admin/carriers', name:'Carriers', component: Carriers },
 { path: '/admin/carriers/new', name:'CarriersNew', component: Carriers },
```

I can't be going to the add page from the index page. How can I go to that page please help me.

Comment: Please be more specific. What happens when you click the button? Is the alert appearing? Is the URL changing? Do you get an error message in the console?

Comment: Yes, alert message is coming and url also changing. And I am getting error like `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <carrier-add> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
`